# Programming a haskell matrix-solver for learning, runtime logic errors present

Tags: haskell, recursion, matrix

I've been learning Haskell seriously for a about a week and a half now, and took inspiration from my linear algebra classes to make a matrix solver. The first step of this is to make a determinant function, but I wanted to go the extra mile and make a function that could solve higher dimension (4x4, 5x5, etc...) matrices.

I'm pretty proud of what I have, considering it's all I've learned, and I've been able to address all errors I've gotten on my on until this point thanks to the Haskell compiler. However, it's at this point I am at a loss. The code below will compile in GHCI with no issues:

```
elerem :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
elerem x xs = init first ++ sec
    where
     first = fst split
     sec   = snd split
     split = splitAt x xs

neglist :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
neglist (x:y:rest) = x:(negate y):(neglist rest)
neglist [x] = [x]

determin :: (Num a, Enum a) => [[a]] -> a
determin xf
    |length (head xf) /= length xf = 0
    |(length xf == 2) && (length (head xf) == 2) = cofactor xf
    |otherwise = sum (zipWith (*) (neglist (head xf)) (sizedown xf))
        where
         sizedown xf = [(determin (cut (tail xf) 1)), (determin (cut (tail xf) 2))..(determin (cut (tail xf) (length xf)))]
         cut xf x = map (elerem x) xf
         cofactor xf = head (head xf) * last (last xf) - head (last xf) * last (head xf)
```

And from my testing so far, runs successfully with and 2x2 matrix, and some, but not all, 3x3 matrices. Since I'm not actually getting any error messages I'm not sure where I went wrong exactly in the code, all I can see is that my code is not giving the same answers that matrix calculators are on the internet.

My one clue is that when starting with a 3x3 identity matrix, my code runs the very obvious answer of 1. Changing element values in the identity matrix also changes the answer to be correct, except with the first value (or columns) of the second and third matrix (or row). It seems the former intentionally messes up answers, and the latter is ignored by calculation and treated as 0.
I feel that this will be a harder problem to solve than normal with the lack of helpful error messages, and I am not experienced enough yet to picture the function expansion process running in my head to find the exact center of the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Test your negllist function.

Comment: Why do you need `Enum a´? Don't you want your function to work with real or complex matrices?

Comment: I noticed the problem with neglist, thank you n.m I've corrected it so that list sizes of 2 do not cause a runtime error. Unfortunately, this did not correct the problem. As for the Enum typeclass, I honestly couldn't tell you. If I do not include it ghci will throw an error at me saying it's needed when calling sizedown. I can post the detailed error message on request if needed.

Comment: It looks like you are misled by the `..` operator. It doesn't do what you think it does. `[1, 2 .. 5]` expands to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, but `[f(1), f(2) .. f(5)]` does not expand to `[f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4), f(5)]`

Comment: It doesn't? I remember trying it out to make sure in ghci. Maybe I was mistaken.   EDIT: Oh no it doesn't. What should I implement instead? A mapping of some kind? List comprehension?

Comment: ghci is telling you you need `Enum` because of the way you are using the `..` operator, but you are not using it correctly.

Comment: Yes you can do what you need with either map or list comprehension.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not too suave with either at the moment, can I get a hint of some kind? I feel that a list comprehension would be the best way but am not familiar with them in the slightest.

Comment: try [debugging](https://wiki.haskell.org/Debugging) the code.

Comment: For which inputs does the program fail?

Comment: `[f i | i <- [1, 2 .. 5]]` does the mapping through a list comprehension.

Comment: In `elerem` you can simplify to `... where (first, sec) = splitAt x xs`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `..` **only** generates arithmetic sequence based on the computed *result* of the parameters.

In particular,

```
[(f 1), (f 2) .. (f 5)]
```

is not the same as

```
[(f 1), (f 2), (f 3), (f 4), (f 5)]
```

, instead it is equal to

```
let a=f 1; b=f 2; c=f 5 in [a,b..c]
```

[Try it yourself](https://tio.run/#%23y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hQsEWiLUUKrhyEzPzgJyCosy8EgUVhWiNNAVDTR0FIGWkqaCnB2KYasb@/w8A) with some nonlinear function, for example `f x = x*x`.

In order to generate `[(f 1), (f 2), (f 3), (f 4), (f 5)]` you can use `map f [1..5]` or list comprehension `[f i | i <- [1..5]]`.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Unfortunately even after correcting this error with list comprehension (at least I think so, with sizedown xf = [(determin (cut (tail xf) i)) | i <- [1,2..(length xf - 1)]] ) I am still receiving the same issue. For example, the nested list/matrix [[1,0,0],[4,1,0],[55,0,1]] when entered into my code has an output of 1, which is definitely not the determinant of that matrix.

Comment: @Sagarmatha [It is indeed 1](https://tio.run/#%23y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxMEltcShutpQx0DHoFan2kTHEEybmgIFDGtr//8HAA).

Comment: I apologize, I picked a bad example to show my error with. How about this one [[8,13,3],[5,3,9],[11,6,3]]. My programs solution is 732, but calculators online are saying 723.

Answer (score 0):

In response to my last comment with the matrix that was giving a determinant of 732 instead of the correct answer of 723, I have discovered the answer myself. It seems that (length xf - 1) is incorrect, simply (length xf) is acceptable. Thank you all for the help!